# Android - Start background service in a correct manner

Tags: android, service, background

I've read the documentation about services and many examples on the web. However, most examples just include the same code and I still don't understand the life cyle of a background service completely.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Start Activity

  > Activity starts a service, receiving location data
- Exit Activity

  > Service keeps collecting
- Start Activity

  > Bind to service and do some stuff, e.g. display some results

And this is what I've done to achive it:

- Implemented a service (not an IntentService)
- tried to start it in two ways:

  1. Start the service by binding to it:

     `bindService(intent, myLocationService, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

     This results in the service beeing created when the activity starts and beeing destroyed, when I call unbindService(...), e.g. in the onStop() method of the activity.
  2. Start the service by creating it, explicitly:

     `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);`
     `startService(intent);`

     This results in the service beeing created when the activity starts. When exiting the activity, the services crashes (although, I've implemented all cleaning up) and gets started again. When starting the activity again, the services starts once more, too.

So, how can I start, bind and unbind a serivce gracefully, without all that crashing and restarting behaviour?

These are the relevant code lines of the service:

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service {

    final IBinder myServiceBinder = new MyServiceBinder();

    public static class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

        MyLocationService service;
        boolean bound = false;

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            MyServiceBinder binder = (MyServiceBinder)iBinder;
            service = binder.getService();
            bound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            bound = false;
        }

        public MyLocationService getService() {
            return service;
        }

        public boolean isBound() {
            return bound;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Binder for GPSService
     */
    public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
        MyLocationService getService() {
            return MyLocationService.this;
        }
    }

    public MyLocationService() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myServiceBinder;
    }


}
```

These are the relevant code lines of the activity:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyLocationService.MyServiceConnection myServiceConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);
        bindService(intent, myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unbindService(myServiceConnection);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Depending on what your requirements are, should be onPause() onResume() or onStart() and onStop().

If you want the service to run in the background you could use

```
/**
     * Called when all clients have disconnected from a particular interface
     * published by the service.  The default implementation does nothing and
     * returns false.
     * 
     * @param intent The Intent that was used to bind to this service,
     * as given to {@link android.content.Context#bindService
     * Context.bindService}.  Note that any extras that were included with
     * the Intent at that point will <em>not</em> be seen here.
     * 
     * @return Return true if you would like to have the service's
     * {@link #onRebind} method later called when new clients bind to it.
     */ public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
       return false;    }
```

onRebind() to do something.